# Is it possible to make a image search filter just using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this html file ,I would like to add a image search filter functionality. For example, there are three images which consists of one Naruto image, one Superman image and one Batman image.
So, I would like to add the functionality like when I type "N or n" ,only the Naruto image shows hiding the other two and same for the rest two.
I think making the images run through an array would work but couldn't do so for images and I have seen many youtube videos but most of them use jQuery,electron but I would like to use only Javascript.

The file screenshot and the code(HTML and CSS) are given below:
[sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cka5l.png)

HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="searchbox_container">
    <div class="searchbox">
      <input type="text" name=" " placeholder="Search" class="search">
    </div>
  </div>
     
    <div class="image_container">
        <img src="images/naruto.png" alt="" 
         class="actionimages">
        <img src="images/batman.png" alt="" 
         class="actionimages">
        <img src="images/superman.png" alt="" 
         class="actionimages">
    </div>


  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
 <style>
    body {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .container {
      width: 700px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: black;
    }

    input {
      border: 2px solid darkgoldenrod;
      background-color: yellow;
      border-radius: 2px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 10px;
      padding: 0 10px;
      font-size: smaller;
      color: black;
    }

    .searchbox {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .image_container
    { width:300px;
      border:2px solid yellow;
      clear:both;
      margin:0 auto;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
    .image_container img{
      width:90px;
      margin-right:auto;
    }
  </style>
```

Pardon for any mistakes.Thank you.

Comment: it is like you need to filter by filename of the images?

Comment: does that mean that if I keep the file names of the images respectively,then searching will be based on the filename ?

Comment: we need to somehow know that which image is batman or like anything

Comment: Thats y I asked can we rely the filename so that we can search the user query is present in the filename or not

Comment: oh,shall I add id's in the images and edit the question?

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand the question earlier and to your question, yes the query can be based  on the filenames

Comment: then you could use my solution below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I understood from your comments

[Fiddled here](https://jsfiddle.net/80Lqa5wt/1/)

```
var input=document.querySelector('.search');
var images=document.querySelectorAll('.image_container > img');

input.addEventListener('keydown',function(){
    for(var i=0; i<images.length;i++)
  {
        if(new RegExp(this.value).test(images[i].src))
      {      
        images[i].style.display ='block'
      }
      else
      {
        images[i].style.display ='none'
      }
      console.log(images[i].src)
  }
  
})
```

Comment: added fiddle example

Comment: May be you would have got unexpected result in the fiddle. Thats coz i forgot to save it before posting it in here. check now

Comment: Thank you, it worked. Can you please explain the code?

Comment: I just created an event for the textbox when user types. When it fires, I checked whether any of the image url contains the user typed value(look at the loop). if it contains, show or else hide it

Comment: (new RegExp(this.value).test(images[i].src)) , please explain this line of code

Comment: it is regular expression, simply testing whther the user input contains in a particular file name

Answer (score 1):

in short you can use javasscript to search for image.
how you implement the search however is up to you.

one way to do so is to use data attribute for your images `data-tags="naruto"` and `data-tags="batman"` and so on.

As you can see in the example below I created an attribute for tags and added the names you want to the tags such as batman image has batman tag attribute.

Then in the javascript I get all the images when the user enters something into the search text box and loop through those images.

in the loop first i hide every image then check with the if statement if the image tag has the searched text in it by using `indexOf` if the tag has the search text then I show the image

```js
function search(){
  var searchText = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
  var images = document.querySelectorAll(".image_container > img");
  
  if(searchText.length > 0){
    images.forEach((image) => {
      image.classList.add("hide");
      if(image.dataset.tags.indexOf(searchText) > -1){
        image.classList.remove("hide");
      }
    });
  }else{
    images.forEach((image) => {
        image.classList.remove("hide");
    });
  }
}
```

```css
body {
      background-color: black;
    }

    .container {
      width: 700px;
      height: 400px;
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: black;
    }

    input {
      border: 2px solid darkgoldenrod;
      background-color: yellow;
      border-radius: 2px;
      width: 100px;
      height: 10px;
      padding: 0 10px;
      font-size: smaller;
      color: black;
    }

    .searchbox {
      float: right;
      margin-top: 5px;
      margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .image_container
    { width:300px;
      border:2px solid yellow;
      clear:both;
      margin:0 auto;
      margin-top:50px;
    }
    .image_container img{
      width:90px;
      margin-right:auto;
    }
    
    
    .hide{
    display:none;
    }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="searchbox_container">
    <div class="searchbox">
      <input type="text" name=" " placeholder="Search" class="search" id="searchInput" onkeyup="search()">
    </div>
  </div>
     
    <div class="image_container">
        <img data-tags="naruto" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-psd/3d-gold-logo-mockup-facade-sign_204971-162.jpg?size=664&ext=jpg" alt="" 
         class="actionimages">
        <img data-tags="batman" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/side-view-man-dancing_23-2148666505.jpg?size=664&ext=jpg" alt="" 
         class="actionimages">
        <img data-tags="superman" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/beautiful-floral-invitation-card-template_21799-4192.jpg?size=664&ext=jpg" alt="" 
         class="actionimages">
    </div>


  </div>
```